# What timezone / format IIS AppPool recycle time is using?

Tags: iis, utc, gmt

I have following problem

AppPool reset time is set to 4:45. Hovewer reset is done at 6:45.

I live in GMT+2 time zone.

Has anyone know what timezone / format is used by this setting in IIS ?
Should i use 2:45 value to get it recycled on 4:45 ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

It will use the time set on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Any time/setting on the server will always go by what the server clock is set to wither it be IIS AppPool reset, scheduled tasks, or anything else that goes off a time. By default Windows server installs will set there time zone to GMT +0 so if your GMT + 2 then anything you set on the server will run at two hours a head (like your 4:45 running at 6:45). You can either manually account for this when you set things up or, if you have root access to the server, you can just adjust the time zone settings from the clock like you would on your desktop so the server time is set to your time zone.